# Using calculations inside dataframe always leads to error: non numeric argument

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
mydata <- structure(list(
   max_L = c("1,71", "1,44", "2,35", "1,64", "3", "1,73"), 
   max_W = c("2,24", "3,14", "1,67", "2,5", "1,57", "2,22" )), 
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to take each row and make the following calculation:

```
 (1/ value of max_L)+(1/ value of max_W)
```

Then I want to put these results into a new column. How can I do that?

Comment: make sure your columns are numeric. Check it using `str(df)`

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a new column to your dataframe `mydata` like this:

```
mydata$col3 <- 1 / mydata$col1 + 1 / mydata$col2
```

**EDIT** after OP showed his data:

Your data is in character format. You have to transform it into numerics first.
If you obtained your data from an external source via `read.table` (or a similar function) you can set the decimal separator: `dec = ","`.

However in your case you can do the following:

```
mydata[,1] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", mydata[,1]))
mydata[,2] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", mydata[,2]))
mydata$col3 <- 1 / mydata[,1] + 1 / mydata[,2]
```

Comment: If I do that i get the error: non numeric argument for binary operator

Comment: This means your data is not numeric therefore you cannot divide and add it.
Maybe we can help you better if you show us part of your data. For example you can post the output of `dput(head(mydata))`.

Comment: structure(list(max_L = c("1,71", "1,44", "2,35", "1,64", "3", 
"1,73"), max_W = c("2,24", "3,14", "1,67", "2,5", "1,57", "2,22"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")